# Error in Eclipse prediction

Tags: java, eclipse, prediction

I've got a weird error in Java prediction since an hour ago and it's really annoying. The problem is when Eclipse wants to predict anything, after some seconds a message box pops up and says:

> "Multiple Problems Have occurred".

In detail area it says:

> An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info".
>   sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.getEncodedBytes(J)[B"

The dialog image:
[image]

workspace log:

> !MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info".
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.getEncodedBytes(J)[B
>       at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.getEncodedBytes(Native Method)
>       at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:134)
>       at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getURLContents(JavaElement.java:848)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getJavadocContents(BinaryType.java:1039)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryMethod.getAttachedJavadoc(BinaryMethod.java:717)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2.getHTMLContent(JavadocContentAccess2.java:533)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ProposalInfo.extractJavadoc(ProposalInfo.java:90)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ProposalInfo.computeInfo(ProposalInfo.java:75)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ProposalInfo.getInfo(ProposalInfo.java:60)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.getAdditionalProposalInfo(AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.java:582)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.AdditionalInfoController$3.run(AdditionalInfoController.java:106)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Comment: You use an Oracle JVM?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Is there any related stack trace in your workspace log @ `workspace_root/.metadata/.log`?

Comment: @Lolo yes there is. I've updated the question.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if i **disconnect** the connection everything works fine then. does eclipse checks internet for documentation or sth like that(in prediction)? i don't want them. how to disable this feature?